# Powershell Script for Removing Windows updates (APC_Index_BSOD)

Tags: arrays, powershell

Looking for an some help finding an easy way to remove windows updates via PowerShell, however I believe I have ran into several issues.

**Goals**

1. Check against and uninstall updates based off the data in the `$data_array`
2. Pause Windows updates until a Hotfix or Update can be pressed
3. Understand how jobs work better

**Issues**

1. I don't believe the `$data` is being sent to the `wusa /uninstall /kb:$data /promptrestart` the main reason I believe this is the error from Windows update standalone installer throws an error without the package number (FIG. 1)
2. Every job is firing off all at once instead of being staggered, having very limited experience with jobs I don't know where to start on troubleshooting. I have tried by using `Get-Job | Retrieve-Job` but don't seem to get much information of status or returned variables
3. I would like to name the jobs so I know more specifically which ones have complete or which step they are at

**Code Snippet**

```
# Updates to Find
$data_array =@('KB5000802','KB5000808','KB5000822','KB5000809')

$commands = @()
# Checks Which update is installed
$commands += {
    $Name = "Check Updates"
    foreach($data in $data_array)
    {
        if(wmic qfe list brief /format:table | Select-String -Pattern $data -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch)
        {
            $commands+=$data
        }
    }
}

# Uninstall Update
$commands += {
    echo "Uninstalling Found Update of: "$data
    wusa /uninstall /kb:$data /promptrestart
}

# Stops Windows Update
$commands += {
    net stop wuauserv
    net pause wuauserv
    net stop bits
    net pause bits
    net stop dosvc
    net pause dosvc
}

# Runs the Jobs
foreach($command in $commands){
    start-job $command
}
```

**Output from PS**

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
39     Job39           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
41     Job41           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
43     Job43           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

**Figure 1**

[image: Error Windows Update Standalone Installer]

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, and additional information can be supplied as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the goal of using jobs here? Normally they are used only when you want things done in parallel, but in your case everything should be done sequentially, so there is no point in using jobs. You are just complicating your script.

Comment: No reason other than that was how a couple of my co-workers were trying to lead me to-do it. If there is a better way i am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify the script by removing the job stuff. Unless you actually need to run things in the background, it just complicates matters. Even when background operations are needed it will be helpful to first create a working linear script before parallelizing.

```
# Updates to find
$searchUpdates = 'KB5000802','KB5000808','KB5000822','KB5000809'

Write-Host "Checking whether the following updates are installed: $($searchUpdates -join ', ')"

# Checks which updates are installed

$allUpdates = wmic qfe list brief /format:table

$foundUpdates = $searchUpdates | Where-Object { 
    $allUpdates | Select-String -Pattern $_ -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch }

if( $foundUpdates ) {
    Write-Host "Found the following installed updates: $($foundUpdates -join ', ')"

    # Uninstall the found updates

    foreach( $update in $foundUpdates ) {
        Write-Host "Uninstalling found update of: $update"
        wusa /uninstall /kb:$update /promptrestart

        # TODO: check $LASTEXITCODE to determine whether removal was successful
    }

    Write-Host 'Stopping windows update...'

    net stop wuauserv
    net pause wuauserv
    net stop bits
    net pause bits
    net stop dosvc
    net pause dosvc
}
else {
    Write-Host 'None of these updates are installed.'
}
```

Further changes:

- removed array subexpression operator `@()` as comma-separated list already defines an array
- query `wmic` only once to improve performance
- replaced the first `foreach` by a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) statement.
- renamed some variables for clarity
- added more logging so you can verify the intermediate results
- replaced `echo` with `Write-Host` which makes it easier for future visitors to look up documentation